# If I set up HSTS on a domain that already implements a 301 redirect, which will take precedence?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, hsts

Ok, so the scenario is that we have a http domain which currently uses a 301 redirect, we want to change this domain to no longer 301 redirect, and instead to be the main domain for said website.

The problem here is that 301 redirects are cached forever, so this isn't really feasible.

We do however want to change the domain to run on https only, and the https domain doesn't have any redirect set whatsoever.

So I'm wondering if I implement HSTS on a domain that already implements a 301 redirect, will the user be forwarded to the HTTPS version of the page (which currently has no redirect in place). This is presuming that they've already got the 301 redirect cached in their browser.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find any information about whether HSTS or the cached 301 redirect would take precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSTS should take precedence as that happens in the browser - before any message is sent (or any cached redirect is used in place of a request being sent).

However this is easily enough tested so would suggest you confirm it yourself.

And yes I really wish browsers would honour cache expiry times of 301s and/or expiry them periodically. Pretty annoying.

Comment: I should also clarify that you will need to go to the real domain to read the HSTS header (or preload it) to activate it. So if your 301 takes you off site that might require some extra through.